# ShareKit - Flickr integration - Want to bypass (or at least auto fill) attributes dialog

Tags: ios, sharekit, flickr

I'm integrating ShareKit into an app and all is working as desired except for the following: when I send to the Flickr sharer I am prompted with the attributes dialog:

[image: flickr screen cap]

Ideally I'd like to suppress the presentation of this dialog or if that is not possible, at least fill in the Title, Description and Tag fields with the variables from my app.  Note that if I toggle the "Auto Share" switch to "On" the dialog is still presented next time through.

If I don't enter values for the Title, Description and Tag fields the values that I specify in my app for the SHKItem object that I allocate are passed up to Flickr and appear with the image.  If I override the values in this dialog then the image displayed on Flickr has those values, which is not desirable in my use case.

For Flickr authentication I've set the consumer key, secret key and callback URL in the SHKConfiguator file and put a matching URL Scheme in the URL Types/URL Identifier row in the info.plist.

I'd appreciate any insight as to how to accomplish bypassing this dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  See https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues/292.